# Getting EditableText to wrap its text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create an `EditableText` that adjusts its width to the length of its text. However, my `EditableText` always takes over all available horizontal space.

**My Widget:**

```
                    EditableText(
                        controller: TextEditingController(),
                        cursorColor: MyColors.black,
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        focusNode: FocusNode(),
                        style: TextStyle(),
                    )
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351773/7604775) will be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Widget` inside a `Expanded`.

Comment: From the documentation: "Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex expand to fill the available space in the main axis." That's exactly the thing I **don't** want to achieve. I want the TextField to be as small as possible, but the text should fit in ("wrap"). I'm sorry if my question was misleading.

Comment: Try using `TextField` widget without `Expanded` wrapped around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a forceLine property. By default it's true and forces a line to take the whole available horizontal space. Just change it to false.

Comment: Expanded needed, not necessary to use forceLine