# Shrink a field text to a smaller width than the hintText

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I would link to create a `TextField` that shrinks to the text inside.
To do so I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62848291/12066144) that says to use an [`IntrinsicWidth`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) widget.
It works well, but if I specify a `hintText`, the width of the `TextField` won't be smaller than the width of the `hintText` even if the user enters a very short text.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50,
            width: 300,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              child: IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'My very very long hint', // Remove it and the text field can be as small as the text inside
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Here is a text field with no hint and a small text:
[image]

The width of the text field is the width of the text inside, which is what I want. ✔️

---

Here is the empty field with a hint:
[image]

When there is no text, the width of the text field is the width of the hint, which is what I want. ✔️

---

Here is the text field with a hint a long text that the hint:
[image]

The field's width is the width of the text inside, which is what I want. ✔️

---

And here is a non-empty field with a hint and a small text:
[image]

As you can see the field width is the width of the hint and not the text inside (which is not what I want ❌).

How can I force it to be the width of the actual text inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Set field width to the width of the text and not the hint

This was possible by using the **onChanged**() function in the TextField widget as shown below.

Also to be able to use setState, **MyApp** class needs to be a **StatefulWidget**.

```
onChanged: (value) => {
    if (value.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
            hText = '';
        })
    } else {
        setState(() {
            hText = 'My very very long hint';
        })
    }
}
```

### 2. The Two Containers wrapping the TextField

I noticed despite using the **IntrinsicWidth**, the two containers are the ones constraining the size of the **TextField**.

If you were using the containers to set the **TextField** visible, another way to do that is to set the borders of the TextField.

The body of the Scaffold can look like this:

```
Center(
    child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) => {
                if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                    setState(() {
                        hText = '';
                    })
                } else {
                    setState(() {
                        hText = 'My very very long hint';
                    })
                }
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal),
                ),
                hintText:
                hText, // Remove it and the text field can be as small as the text inside
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

### Full Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String hText = 'My very very long hint';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => {
                if (value.isNotEmpty)
                  {
                    setState(() {
                      hText = '';
                    })
                  }
                else
                  {
                    setState(() {
                      hText = 'My very very long hint';
                    })
                  }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                //When the TextFormField is ON focus
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal),
                ),
                hintText:
                    hText, // Remove it and the text field can be as small as the text inside
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally change the `hintText` based on the content of your `TextEditingController`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _controller = useTextEditingController();
    final _editing = useState(false);
    _controller.addListener(() => _editing.value = _controller.text.isNotEmpty);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 300,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  IntrinsicWidth(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: _editing.value
                            ? '' // empty hintText if field is not empty
                            : 'My very very long hint',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```